# Why do some of Intel's intrinsics take const immediates, while others are non-const?

Tags: c++, x86, intel, intrinsics

[Intel's intrinsic guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) seems to be making a mysterious distinction with immediate values. They label some as const and some not as const. In practice the both types regardless need to be compile time constants or compiler will complain. I'm just wondering why the distinction? Something I'm missing?

Here's an example of what intel says:

```
_mm_blend_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i b, const int imm8)
_mm_srli_si128 (__m128i a, int imm8)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Intel's old stuff being less well-written than their new stuff, assuming you consider `const` an improvement.

Note that `blend_epi16` is SSE4.1, while `srli_si128` is SSE2.  Probably they decided to reinforce the point that the argument needs to be a compile-time constant when they added intrinsics for SSE4.1.

The AVX2 intrinsic for the 256bit version uses const:  `__m256i _mm256_srli_si256 ( __m256i a, const int imm)`.  This basically confirms that they just hadn't thought of `const` yet, since they started using `const` for the same instruction.

Also note that they were so unhappy with the `_mm_srli_si128` name for the [`psrldq` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSRLDQ.html) that they introduced a new name for it: `_mm_bsrli_si128` should be preferred in new code, to makes it clearer it's a byte-shift, not a 128bit wide bit-shift.  It's a lot different from `_mm_srli_epi64`.  The instruction reference manual unfortunately doesn't mention the `bsrli` name.

---

AVX512 load/store intrinsics will use `void*` instead of `__m128i*`, which is another nice change.

So basically Intel does things differently because the old way was sub-optimal, not because they have to.

Comment: Interesting, according to my identifier not found errors, _mm_bsrli_si128 is not available in VS 2015. However, _mm_srli_si128 is available.

Comment: @Volatile: that's unfortunate.  [Intel's intrinsics guide lists it](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=bsrli&expand=552), and gcc/clang support it.  Maybe it isn't actually standard.  I wish it was, because it's obviously clearer.  That's really unfortunate that it's not portable to MSVC.  You included the catch-all `immintrin.h` or `x86intrin.h`, right?

Comment: Yes I get the identifier error with immintrin.h included.

Comment: The catch-all in MSVC is actually `intrin.h`, rather than `x86intrin.h`, but of course the more specific `ammintrin.h` and `immintrin.h` work as well. Microsoft's headers don't appear to have `_mm_bsrli_si128` (yet?). You can define it yourself if you want: `#define _mm_bsrli_si128(a, imm) _mm_srli_si128((a), (imm))`

Comment: @CodyGray: Simpler to leave out the args in the `#define _mm_bsrli_si128 _mm_srli_si128`.  I'd still call `immintrin.h` a catch-all for Intel vector intrinsics.  It includes everything from SSE through (currently) AVX512.  Good point that it doesn't include AMD intrinsics, though.  But new vector extensions like AVX512 get added to it, unlike other headers like `pmmintrin.h`.  IIRC, there is no "specific" header for AVX512; you're just supposed to include `immintrin`.  (gcc's avx512fintrin.h has a `#error "Never use <avx512fintrin.h> directly; include <immintrin.h> instead."`)